# How do I monitor SharePoint Online API usage?

Tags: sharepoint-online, performance, api, monitoring

Our company stores projects in Office 365 SharePoint Online, creating one site per project utilizing site templates.

We then use SharePoint Workflows, PowerBI, Microsoft Flow, PowerApps, and custom C# programs using CSOM, to view and manipulate the information stored in SharePoint.

The problem is, we have recently been experiencing performance issues, and we are unsure of where exactly the problem could be. Is this being caused by an unannounced change to SharePoint Online by Microsoft, or a new PowerApp created by an inexperienced programmer, or because we have so many "solutions" accessing SharePoint via the API?

Is there a way to look at the performance of the API calls made to SharePoint Online, so that we have a starting point to diagnose what is causing our SharePoint Online instance to seem so slow?